# Adjective for 'being able to use magic' or 'being able to cast spells'

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, german

Playing a German pen & paper RPG I noticed that they are using an adjective 'zaubermächtig' for which I could not find an appropriate English equivalent. The best I could come up with is *being able to use magic*, which does not sound as elegant as the German word.

The German word is a compound of the noun 'Zauber' which could be translated as *spell*, *magic* or *enchantment* and the adjective 'mächtig', in this case comparable to the English *-able* with a connotation of being competent.

Is there an adjective for this in English?

### Examples

- Kreuvf is *zaubermächtig*.
- I didn't know that <presumably normal person without magic powers> is actually *zaubermächtig*.

Comment: The usual practice in D&D and its derivatives is to employ the noun *spellcaster* as either a predicative or an attributive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose *thaumaturgic*, derived from *thaumaturge*, a 'worker of wonders or miracles; magician' according to dictionary.com.

Alternatively, *sorcerous*, 'of the nature of, or involving, sorcery'.

Comment: I think that 'of the nature of sorcery' best describes what I am looking for. Thank you and everybody else very much for your answers.

Answer (score 3):

The closest word I can think of is "magical", which would be "possesses magical properties"; that seems a little off, however. You could try describing them as a noun (Kreuvf is a wizard/sorcerer/mage/magician).

If you really want something that functions as an adjective, though, magic-capable or spellcast-capable sound like they should work.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative: **a wizard**. In the barest sense, implies a type.

Is **a caster** (of magic) - carries inherent properties of magic, but unspecified. Not a wizard, mage, or specific, just a caster, base class, if you will. User of spells, whatever.

Maybe **a magician**? Besides parlor-trick implications.

*Please don't go with magical, Unicorns are magical*.

Something more removed is to **have powers**, or as the example would go, "I didn't think *Bob* has powers.".

Last I can think of is **gifted**. Is an adjective.

Whichever floats your boat.

*EDIT*: Fixed some mistakes found by comments.

Comment: Most of these aren't adjectives, and your one example of using magic as an adjective is parenthesised, ungrammatical, and seems to emphasise the noun?

Comment: I know they aren't - i don't foresee either of these being used, but there isn't really a good equivalent/alternative to what's being asked for, or so i think. Thus i provided something different that could work. Ungrammatical how?

Comment: You've doubled the article.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps **bewitching**, event if mostly used in its figurative sens, i.e. captivating, seducing, fascinating.

Example: *The woman was enchanting, likely casting a bewitching spell over him*.

Answer (score 0):

In the same vein as Graffito's **bewitching** and **enchanting,** there's also **glamourous,** **spellbinding**, **fascinating**, **enthralling** and **charming,** all of which I think were originally related to magic. I see a trend.

Comment: Those do not describe the **ability** to use magic or cast a spell.